# Why is ng-change one step behind in the console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u3olPFyiT7tFdKKVvzZf?p=preview

I have a list and an input that filters said list.

If you look at the number for "results" on screen as you type, that's correct. But if you look at the number in the console, it seems to always be one step behind.

Why? And how to solve it?

JS:

```
  $scope.users = [
    'mike',
    'john',
    'pete'
  ]

  $scope.results = [];

  $scope.count_results = function() {
    console.log($scope.results.length)
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user_name" ng-change="count_results()">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="user in results = (users | filter: user_name) | limitTo: 3">{{user}}</li>
</ul>
Results: {{results.length}}
```

Comment: The *"why"* part is fairly simple...what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `ng-change` is executed before the filter is filtering the list. In the moment when `ng-change` is executed the `result` is not set to the new list so the console output show's the length of the old list before filtering.

**EDIT:**

You can fix this problem when you execute the filtering inside the `ng-change` mehtod and not in the view. And then show only the result. See my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aXEOUlryaA7bN2i3ptTp?p=preview)

```
  $scope.count_results = function() {
      $scope.results = $filter('filter')($scope.users, $scope.user_name);
      console.log($scope.results.length)
  }
```

Comment: So how do I make the console display the correct `result` number?

Answer (score 0):

Both `ng-model` and `ng-change` add a `change` event listener to the input they are applied on. When you type into input the events handlers are executed (among others your `count_results`). The event listeners cause module value change and trigger a new `$digest` cycle.

The `$digest` cycles is where angular compares old model values with new ones and updates the view accordingly. That's when the filter is applied with an updated criteria to narrow down the list.

You you add i.e.

```
<span class="{{count_results()}}"></span>
```

You'll see the `console.log` is printed many times, with the last value always in sync. However this is pretty useless and I suspect you'll much rather want to have `$watch` inside your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('results.length', function(newValue, oldValue){
   console.log('new value is', newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with `$watch`. I edit the code as follows:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R3QRa1bhGyNwAeU6OOVb?p=preview

Comment: Serious flaw in approach used to create watch. Will add a new watch for every letter entered. Is compounding watches. Don't create it inside event handler. Also should post code in answer and use demo as proof of concept only

Comment: @charlietfl - what would be your solution?

Comment: Can use the watch... but don't create new one every time UI event triggers. Look at console when you type `p..e..t..e` slowly